# SQL: alternatives and substitutions for GROUPING SETS and PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, olap

I've got code like this:

```
SELECT id, YEAR(datek) AS YEAR, COUNT(*) AS NUM
FROM Orders
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
(
    (id, YEAR(datek)),
    id,
    YEAR(datek),
    ()
);
```

It gives me this output:

```
1   NULL    4
2   NULL    11
3   NULL    6
NULL    NULL    21
1   2006    36
2   2006    56
3   2006    51
NULL    2006    143
1   2007    130
2   2007    143
3   2007    125
NULL    2007    398
1   2008    79
2   2008    116
3   2008    73
NULL    2008    268
NULL    NULL    830
1   NULL    249
2   NULL    326
3   NULL    255
```

What I need to do is write it without "grouping sets" (nor cube or rollup) but with the same result. I thought about writing three different queries and join them with "union". I try something like "null" in group by settings but it does not work.

```
SELECT id, YEAR(datek) AS rok, COUNT(*) AS NUM
FROM Orders
GROUP BY id, YEAR(datek)
UNION
SELECT id, YEAR(datek) AS rok, COUNT(*) AS NUM
FROM Orders
GROUP BY id, null
order by id, YEAR(datek)
```

I also have a question about "PIVOT". What kind of syntax can replace query with "PIVOT"?

Thanks for your time and all the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in that you need separate queries, although you actually need 4, and rather than `GROUP BY NULL`, just group by the columns in the corresponding grouping set, and replace the column in the `SELECT` with `NULL`:

```
SELECT id, YEAR(datek) AS rok, COUNT(*) AS NUM
FROM Orders
GROUP BY id, YEAR(datek)

UNION ALL

SELECT id, NULL, COUNT(*) AS NUM
FROM Orders
GROUP BY id

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, YEAR(datek), COUNT(*) AS NUM
FROM Orders
GROUP BY YEAR(datek)

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, NULL, COUNT(*) AS NUM
FROM Orders
ORDER BY ID, Rok
```

With regard to a replacement for `PIVOT` I think the best alternative is to use a conditional aggregate, e.g. instead of:

```
SELECT  pvt.SomeGroup,
        pvt.[A],
        pvt.[B],
        pvt.[C]
FROM    T
        PIVOT (SUM(Val) FOR Col IN ([A], [B], [C])) AS pvt;
```

You would use:

```
SELECT  T.SomeGroup,
        [A] = SUM(CASE WHEN T.Col = 'A' THEN T.Val ELSE 0 END),
        [B] = SUM(CASE WHEN T.Col = 'B' THEN T.Val ELSE 0 END),
        [C] = SUM(CASE WHEN T.Col = 'C' THEN T.Val ELSE 0 END)
FROM    T
GROUP BY T.SomeGroup;
```

Comment: @GarethD To be pedantic, actually, for pivot, `ELSE NULL` would be the equivalent instead of `ELSE 0`.